# firefox save image from memory/cache

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want find/write a simple add-on for Firefox, just save image to local disk from a web page without re-load it from server. The image is already displayed, so it must be in cache/memory.

For most images, I can just drag the image to Finder, but for some images it doesn't work (maybe the server check the Referer etc.).

I check the XPCOM APIs, but have no idea how to do it.

An example:
http://www.dm5.com/m222757/

Disable all user defined event to the image with firebug etc. Then right click the image in the middle, "Save Image As...", it will save a different image.

Comment: The server has nothing to do with this. If its a background image, you can usually save it out using the inspector and finding its source image. If right clicks are disabled, just google `enable right click firefox plugin` and Im sure you will find a result.

Comment: @somethinghere it's not a background. I know I can do it with firebug/built-in debugger, but it require a lot of work. I want the single-click-save ability.

Comment: If its not a background then right-click and save should always work, there is nothing stopping you from that. If there is, it might be more useful to find out why that is, because if you cannot right click to save then either they created their own right click menu or there is another element on top of it blocking you from clicking it - which means a plugin wouldn't work either.

Comment: @somethinghere It works most of the time, but won't work for some case. I'll find you an example.

Comment: @somethinghere Added an example. Please test it.

Comment: Right click has been disabled on these. Heres an extension for Chrome that will re-enable right clicking: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-right-click/hhojmcideegachlhfgfdhailpfhgknjm?hl=en (tested and works) - Heres one for FireFox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/righttoclick/ - I had no issues with a different image being saved.

Comment: @somethinghere Sorry, bad example. This page only works in China, it will show a different page for visitors not in China. Right now I cannot find another example works in all  countries. I have no problem with the right click, I can enable it easily.

Comment: @somethinghere Updated the example.

Comment: Again, I had no issue saving this image (and exactly this one) by right clicking after the right click has been re-enabled. The thing is, it is almost impossible to know the difference between a user viewing an image and a user downloading it - to the server, both requests are the same. So this should work either way. (Also, chinese/japanese always looks so cool!)

Comment: @somethinghere I got it. The problem isn't the function of browser, it's the image itself. Thanks for your help.